# How to insert legend in plot after a for cycle

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a problem with the insertion of a legend in a 3D plot in MATLAB. 
I have a list of data, in particular I have a `nx3` matrix filled with data to plot and I want to separate this data by applying a threshold.

In my case the threshold is a time, so if the `i`th data is lower than the threshold time it will be plotted in blue color, otherwise in red color.

The code is

```
figure(1)
plot3(ra(1),dec(1),Time2plot(1),'*','Color','r', 'DisplayName', 'observation day');
hold on;
plot3(ra(end),dec(end),Time2plot(end),'*','Color','b','DisplayName', 'next day');
legend show;

for i = 1:length(Time2plot)
    if timeofday(Time2plot(i)) > B(1) && timeofday(Time2plot(i)) < B(2)
        hold on;
        plot3(ra(i),dec(i),Time2plot(i),'*','Color', 'b');

    else
        hold on;
        plot3(ra(i),dec(i),Time2plot(i),'*','Color','r');

    end
end

hold on;
title(['RA Dec in 3D ', date(1,1)]);
xlabel('RA');
ylabel('Dec');
zlabel('Time');
ztickformat('HH:mm:ss');
grid on;
```

where B is the threshold.
The result is [image]

I'd like to have only two line in the legend: 'next day' and 'observation day' and not all the data.

Answer (score 1):

If your figure already has a legend and you use the `legend`-command again, the old legend will be overwritten. So in your case you should be able to do something like this:

```
legend('observation day','next day');
```

Just append this line to your code, and you will end up with a two-entry-legend.
The situation becomes a little trickier, when the legend entries that you want to keep are not the first two. In that case you will first have to permute the `Children` of the axes-object so that they are the first entries. Let's assume `'observation day'` was the 3rd entry of your legend and `'next day'` the 4th. In that case you need to do the following before applying the new legend:

```
h=gca;
h.Children=h.Children([(3:4).';(1:2).';(5:length(h.Children)).'])
```